# TypeError on convolution_filter call from statsmodels

Tags: python, numpy, statsmodels

I'm struggling to do time series decomposition with the `statsmodels`'s `tsa.seasonal_decompose` function, which calls the `convolution_filter` function and raises the following TypeError:

> TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object cannot be interpreted as an index

For instance, when I run the code below (provided by the [StatsModels website](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/stable/release/version0.6.html#seasonal-decomposition)):

```
import statsmodels.api as sm

dta = sm.datasets.co2.load_pandas().data
# deal with missing values. see issue
dta.co2.interpolate(inplace=True)

res = sm.tsa.seasonal_decompose(dta.co2)
res.plot()
```

I get the following stack trace:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------- TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-11-b43f2eda010e> in <module>()
      5 dta.co2.interpolate(inplace=True)
      6 
----> 7 res = sm.tsa.seasonal_decompose(dta.co2)
      8 res.plot()

.../statsmodels/tsa/seasonal.pyc in seasonal_decompose(x, model, filt, freq)
     86             filt = np.repeat(1./freq, freq)
     87 
---> 88     trend = convolution_filter(x, filt)
     89 
     90     # nan pad for conformability - convolve doesn't do it

.../statsmodels/tsa/filters/filtertools.pyc in convolution_filter(x, filt, nsides)
    301                 result[:, i] = signal.convolve(x[:, i], np.r_[0, filt[:, i]],
    302                                                mode='valid')
--> 303     result = _pad_nans(result, trim_head, trim_tail)
    304     if _pandas_wrapper:
    305         return _pandas_wrapper(result)

.../statsmodels/tsa/filters/filtertools.pyc in _pad_nans(x, head, tail)
     26             return x
     27         elif head and tail:
---> 28             return np.r_[[np.nan] * head, x, [np.nan] * tail]
     29         elif tail is None:
     30             return np.r_[[np.nan] * head, x]

TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object cannot be interpreted as an index
```

I've tried with a few other examples and faced the same problem on the Numpy's `_pad_nans` function. I'm using Numpy 1.12.0 and StatsModels 0.6.1.

Does anyone know what's happening?

Comment: which versions of statsmodels and numpy are you using? This might be a incompatibility between an old statmodels and a new numpy. (Or maybe a bug in numpy 0.19.0 that has been fixed in 0.19.1.)

Comment: Just added the versions I'm using

Comment: upgrade statsmodels and it should now work, 0.8 was just released on pip. Just solved the same issue for me.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this exact same error this morning. The issue is due to an incompatibility between `Numpy 1.12.0` and `StatsModels 0.6.1`. It originally showed up as the warning documented [here](https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/2958).

The good news is that it's been fixed in the release candidate for `StatsModels 0.8`. Unfortunately though 0.8 hasn't been released yet and doesn't show up in the usual repositories yet. I got it working by checking out the source from github and building it myself using the instructions [here](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/stable/install.html).

Comment: StatsModels 0.8 is now on pip, so I just ran into this error and have now fixed it by updating StatsModels with 'conda install statsmodels'. 'pip install --upgrade statsmodels' should also do the trick for anyone without conda.

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into the same problem, temporarily rolled back to numpy 1.11 which worked fine `pip install -U numpy==1.11.0` (if you want to save installing StatsModels from source).